# How to combine list to a nested list

Tags: python, list

How would I go about iterating through a list of lists and adding elements from another list?

```
time_list = []
input_list = []

for val in list_of_dict:
    k = (val['Time'])
    zet = (k.split(' '))
    p = (val['Ext. Input 1 digital'])
    #print(p)
    time_list.append(zet[1].split(':'))
    input_list.append(p)
    #print(input_list)

print(time_list)
print(input_list)
```

Output:

```
[['7', '21'], ['7', '28'], ['7', '29'], ['7', '31'], ['7', '43'], ['7', '47'], ['7', '49'], ['7', '56'], ['7', '58'], ['8', '02'], ['8', '03'], ['8', '14'], ['8', '28'], ['8', '34'], ['8', '37'], ['8', '44'], ['8', '44'], ['8', '46'], ['8', '47'], ['8', '56'], ['8', '59'], ['8', '59'], ['9', '00'], ['9', '03'], ['9', '03'], ['9', '05'], ['9', '06'], ['9', '07'], ['9', '22'], ['9', '23'], ['9', '24'], ['9', '28'], ['9', '29'], ['9', '32'], ['9', '32'], ['9', '34'], ['9', '35'], ['9', '43'], ['9', '45'], ['9', '47'], ['9', '48'], ['9', '53'], ['9', '55'], ['9', '59'], ['9', '59'], ['10', '03'], ['10', '04'], ['10', '05'], ['10', '09'], ['10', '10'], ['10', '10'], ['10', '12'], ['10', '12'], ['10', '13'], ['10', '15'], ['10', '19'], ['10', '19'], ['10', '23'], ['10', '25'], ['10', '30'], ['10', '30'], ['10', '33'], ['10', '38'], ['10', '46'], ['10', '51'], ['10', '57'], ['11', '01'], ['11', '01'], ['11', '04'], ['11', '07'], ['11', '08'], ['11', '11'], ['11', '11'], ['11', '12'], ['11', '15'], ['11', '15'], ['11', '15'], ['11', '20'], ['11', '21'], ['11', '34'], ['11', '36'], ['11', '37'], ['11', '38'], ['11', '39'], ['11', '41'], ['11', '44'], ['11', '48'], ['11', '50'], ['11', '50'], ['11', '53'], ['11', '53'], ['11', '56'], ['11', '56'], ['11', '58'], ['11', '59'], ['12', '01'], ['12', '03'], ['12', '06'], ['12', '07'], ['12', '08'], ['12', '09'], ['12', '11'], ['12', '32'], ['12', '33'], ['12', '33'], ['12', '40'], ['12', '42'], ['12', '49'], ['12', '52'], ['12', '53'], ['12', '53'], ['12', '54'], ['12', '55'], ['12', '58'], ['13', '01'], ['13', '01'], ['13', '04'], ['13', '04'], ['13', '07'], ['13', '07'], ['13', '11'], ['13', '11'], ['13', '13'], ['13', '17'], ['13', '17'], ['13', '35'], ['13', '36'], ['13', '38'], ['13', '39'], ['13', '41'], ['13', '42'], ['13', '43'], ['13', '44'], ['13', '44'], ['13', '45'], ['13', '47'], ['13', '48'], ['13', '50'], ['13', '55'], ['13', '57'], ['14', '01'], ['14', '01'], ['14', '02'], ['14', '07'], ['14', '08'], ['14', '16'], ['14', '20'], ['14', '22'], ['14', '22'], ['14', '27'], ['14', '28'], ['14', '30'], ['14', '32'], ['14', '38'], ['14', '39'], ['14', '41'], ['14', '45'], ['14', '50'], ['15', '08'], ['15', '16'], ['15', '20'], ['15', '23'], ['15', '24'], ['15', '30'], ['15', '34'], ['15', '39'], ['15', '40'], ['15', '44'], ['15', '44'], ['15', '44'], ['15', '52'], ['16', '00'], ['16', '01'], ['16', '09'], ['16', '14'], ['16', '15'], ['16', '15'], ['16', '16'], ['16', '20'], ['16', '28'], ['16', '29'], ['16', '38'], ['16', '39'], ['16', '42'], ['16', '42'], ['16', '47'], ['16', '47'], ['16', '56'], ['16', '58'], ['17', '01'], ['17', '02'], ['17', '07'], ['17', '10'], ['17', '19'], ['17', '19'], ['17', '21'], ['17', '21'], ['17', '22'], ['17', '23'], ['17', '29'], ['17', '29'], ['17', '37'], ['17', '39'], ['17', '39'], ['17', '41'], ['17', '46'], ['18', '08'], ['18', '11'], ['18', '12'], ['18', '20'], ['18', '21'], ['18', '30'], ['18', '31'], ['18', '34'], ['18', '35'], ['18', '38'], ['18', '42'], ['18', '49'], ['18', '52'], ['19', '05'], ['19', '09'], ['19', '13'], ['19', '17'], ['19', '17'], ['19', '18'], ['19', '21'], ['19', '27'], ['19', '32'], ['19', '32'], ['19', '41'], ['19', '44'], ['19', '52'], ['19', '53'], ['20', '01'], ['20', '01'], ['20', '10'], ['20', '14'], ['20', '22'], ['20', '22'], ['20', '22'], ['20', '23'], ['20', '26'], ['20', '54'], ['20', '54'], ['21', '00'], ['21', '04'], ['21', '06'], ['21', '14'], ['21', '21'], ['21', '24'], ['21', '26'], ['21', '32'], ['21', '32'], ['21', '40'], ['21', '46'], ['21', '50'], ['21', '51'], ['21', '57'], ['21', '59'], ['22', '09'], ['22', '19'], ['22', '20'], ['22', '21'], ['22', '29'], ['22', '33'], ['22', '41'], ['22', '42'], ['22', '50'], ['22', '52'], ['22', '56'], ['23', '14'], ['23', '18'], ['23', '19'], ['23', '22'], ['23', '23'], ['23', '38'], ['23', '40'], ['23', '42'], ['23', '42'], ['23', '51'], ['23', '55'], ['23', '56'], ['23', '56'], ['0', '00'], ['0', '01'], ['0', '02'], ['0', '03'], ['0', '07'], ['0', '08'], ['0', '08'], ['0', '14'], ['0', '18'], ['0', '27'], ['0', '28'], ['0', '31'], ['0', '33']]
['1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on', '1oFF', '1 on']
```

What I want is this:

```
[['7', '21', '1off'], ['7', '28', '1 on'], ['7', '29', '1off'], ...]]
```

I have tried to iterate through `input_list` and append to `time_list` but it appends starting at the end of `time_list`.

```
for q in input_list:
    time_list.append(q)
    
print(time_list)
```

Comment: Why do you create two lists when you only want one list?

Comment: post your `list_of_dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip` to combine the corresponding elements of the two lists.

```py
res = [[*x, y] for x, y in zip(time_list, input_list)]
```

Alternatively, append everything to `time_list` in the original loop.

```py
time_list.append([*zet[1].split(':'), p])
```